# numpy isin for multi-dimmensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

I have a big array of integers and second array of arrays. I want to create a boolean mask for the first array based on data from the second array of arrays. Preferably I would use the `numpy.isin` but it clearly states in it's documentation:

*The values against which to test each value of element. This argument is flattened if it is an array or array_like. See notes for behavior with non-array-like parameters.*

Do you maybe know some performant way of doing this instead of list comprehension?
So for example having those arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]])
```

I would like to have result like:

```
np.array([
       [True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True]
])
```

Comment: What are the relative dimensions of `a` and `b` - in the real world case?  Look at `in1d` to see what happens with different relative dimensions.  In some cases it makes heavy use `unique` and `sorting`.  It isn't a trivial task.

Comment: @hpaulj I already solved it, please see my comment below. The dimensions are ```a``` is 67455000 and ```b``` is (200, 10000).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `numpy.apply_along_axis` to work with `numpy.isin`:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.isin(a, x), axis=1, arr=b)
```

returns

```
array([[[ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       [[False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False]],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       [[False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False]],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       [[False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False]],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       [[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, True]]])
```

I will update with an edit comparing the runtime with a list comp

EDIT:

Whelp, I tested the runtime, and wouldn't you know, listcomp is faster

```
timeit.timeit("[np.isin(a,x) for x in b]",number=10000, globals=globals()) 
0.37380070000654086
```

vs

```
timeit.timeit("np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.isin(a, x), axis=1, arr=b) ",number=10000, globals=globals())
0.6078917000122601
```

the other answer to this post by [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) is much faster:

```
timeit.timeit("(a == b[...,None]).any(-2)",number=100, globals=globals())                                           
0.007107900004484691
```

and should probably be accepted.

Comment: Thank you for that!
Yes I can confirm that the comprehension is the fastest so far, although I'm working on number code to make it even faster. The solution from @mozway is several times slower for bigger arrays, say 20k elements.

Comment: I'm not sure anything in numpy will be a silver bullet for you. I would recommend looking into numba and iterating that way.

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` needs a (stronger) performance disclaimer.  It does not compile your function, it just iterates on all dimensions except one, and passes the resulting 1d array to your function.  The `lambda` gets called for every "row".

Comment: The broadcasted approach creates a larger temporary array.  Memory mangement for that can slow it down - relative to an iterative approach.  There are tradeoffs.

Comment: @DavidKaftan If you are interested I posted my code that solved the issue for me.

Comment: I saw, thanks for posting! Smart solution to an interesting problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can use broadcasting to avoid any loop (this is however more memory expensive):

```
(a == b[...,None]).any(-2)
```

Output:

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True  True]])
```

Comment: Thats pretty sick. I had no idea you could expand dims using `b[...,None]`

Comment: @David `...` selects all dimensions, `None` adds a new one, thus the comparison is broadcasted to have all combinations. Then we aggregate to a single boolean on this new dimension to keep `True` if there is any `True`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit cheated but ultra fast solution. The cheating is that I sort the seconds matrix before so that I can use binary search.

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def isin_multi(a, b):
    out = np.zeros((b.shape[0], a.shape[0]), dtype=nb.boolean)

    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        for j in nb.prange(b.shape[0]):
            index = np.searchsorted(b[j], a[i])
            if index >= len(b[j]) or b[j][index] != a[i]:
                out[j][i] = False
            else:
                out[j][i] = True
                break

    return out

a = np.random.randint(200000, size=200000)
b = np.random.randint(200000, size=(50, 5000))

b = np.sort(b, axis=1)

start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(20):
    isin_multi(a, b)
print(f"isin_multi {time.perf_counter() - start:.3f} seconds")

start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(20):
    np.array([np.isin(a, ids) for ids in b])
print(f"comprehension {time.perf_counter() - start:.3f} seconds")
```

Results:

```
isin_multi 2.951 seconds. 
comprehension 21.093 seconds
```